# Green energy concept

Tags: batteries

Can you explain this green energy concept? I can’t understand it.
When my notebook energy is almost empty there’s this *save energy green leaf* symbol.
[image: save energy green leaf symbol]
Does this mean the computer is getting its energy from a green energy  source(like solar panels)?
Please explain this better.

Comment: In general, all `pretty pictures` showing you anything `nature-like` related to `energy`, if reaching you through mass-media or any other mass-outreach means, are selling you pure, undiluted, poisonous snake-oil to get your money and feather their own nests while delivering little or nothing in return for it. (Propaganda, in short.) However, in this case, it does just mean that your battery is low and that your notebook is shifting its operating system gears to deal with it. Don't stress.

Comment: do you see solar panels on your notebook?

Answer (score 1):

It's just an indicator for "power saving mode".

As you are already aware, when the battery charge level drops below a certain level the computer changes the power consumption mode to "power saving" which reduces the performance by turning off/down some power-hungry facilities (e.g. screen brightness, CPU and/or GPU performance etc) to increase the time of usage.

The idea behind this is basically to tell you to use your laptop as much as possible without keeping it plugged in, therefore use less power. Because if you keep it plugged in the power scheme will probably switch to "performance" therefore use more power.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol means your notebook tries to conserve power to extend the time until the battery is empty. It shuts down peripherals not in use and lowers it's energy consumption as far as possible.
This has nothing to do with alternative energy sources.

Answer (score 0):

It means the author of that behaviour is taking the opportunity to 'greenwash' themselves or the product, and nag you to save energy.